# Is there anyway to pull the data from another table or another model to drop down list or select box?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0, blazor-server-side

I am using visual studio 2019, Blazor App, Blazor Server App,Asp.netCore 3.0.

In that, I am using 2 Models (Model Gage and Model Department) and 2 different database (Model Gage with Database Calibration and Model Department with Database Erp).

I was created form with Model Gage and trying to retrieve data from Model Department for Select-box.

Model Gage

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace Calibration.Data.Gage
    {
        public partial class GageMaster
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Department { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Section { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string ControlNo { get; set; }
```

For this I am using CalibrationDbContext

Code Example for GageService

```
 public Task<List<GageMaster>>
           GetGageAsync(string strCurrentUser)
        {
            List<GageMaster> NwDset =
                new List<GageMaster>();
            // Get Weather Forecasts  
            NwDset =
                (from Dset in _context.GageMaster                    
                 where Dset.IsObsolete != "Yes"               
                 select Dset).ToList();
            return Task.FromResult(NwDset);
        }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Calibration.Data.ERP
{
    public partial class Department
    {
        public string Departmentcode { get; set; }
        public string Departmentname { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }

    }
```

For this I am using ERPDbContext

Code example for ErpService

```
public Task<List<Department>>
           GetDepartmentAsync()
        {
            List<Department> NwDset =
                new List<Department>();
            // Get Weather Forecasts  
            NwDset =
                (from Dset in _context.Department                      
                 where Dset.Office == "P"
                 //strCurrentUser
                 select Dset).ToList();
            return Task.FromResult(NwDset);
        }
```

---

Razorcomponent Sample code

```
<p>
 <InputText id="Department" class="form-control"
placeholder="Department"
@bind-Value="NwDset.Department" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => NwDset.Department)" />                                         
 </p>


 <p>
  <label for="ControlNo">Control Number:</label>
<InputText id="ControlNo" class="form-control"
 placeholder="Control Number"
 @bind-Value="NwDset.ControlNo" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => NwDset.ControlNo)" />
</p>
```

I want to replace Department Inputtext with Inputselect, Is there anyway to access 2 service at on razorcomponentpage? 
I tried Inherits both Model
@Inherits not allowing more than one class.

I have no issue With Gageservice.

I am trying to call this "GetDepartmentAsync" from ErpService but really I don't know the way. Please help it.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use `@inject` directive to inject GageService and ErpService as follows.

Register the GageService and ErpService in Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<GageService>();
services.AddTransient<ErpService>();
```

Razor component

```
@page "/Test"

@using BlazorApp1.Data.Gage
@using BlazorApp1.Data.ERP
@inject GageService gageService
@inject ErpService erpService

<EditForm Model="@NwDset">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<table border="0" cellpadding="20">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>ControlNo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in NwDset)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <label for="">Department:</label>
                        <InputSelect id="Department" class="form-control" placeholder="Department" @bind-Value="item.Department">
                            @foreach (var department in departments)
                                {
                                <option value="@department.Departmentname">
                                    @department.Departmentname
                                </option>
                                }
                        </InputSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => item.Department)" />
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <label for="ControlNo">Control Number:</label>
                        <InputText id="ControlNo" class="form-control"
                                   placeholder="Control Number"
                                   @bind-Value="item.ControlNo" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => item.ControlNo)" />
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</EditForm>


@code {
List<GageMaster> NwDset;
List<Department> departments;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    NwDset = await gageService.GetGageAsync();
    departments = await erpService.GetDepartmentAsync();
}

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, I tried with my code,working fine.

Now only I got hope on Blazor and Razor Component. 

This is easiest way to bind the data from different model. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RavichandranSankaranarayanan Mark it as the accepted answer then.

Answer (score 0):

To inject a service do not use `@inherits`, use `@inject` instead.
You must register your service in `ConfigureServices`.
[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection).

You can also easily inject multiple dependencies to a razor component using code-behind:

Razor component `Component.razor`:

```
@inherits ComponentModel

...
```

Class `ComponentModel.cs`

```
public class ComponentModel: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected ErpService  ErpService  { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    protected GageService GageService { get; set; }
```

[See more here.](https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-code-behind/).